# How to deploy project multiple branches with docker and traeffik

Tags: docker, docker-compose, branch, reverse-proxy, traefik

I'm trying to setup a docker/traefik config to allow the deployment of my project in different versions on the same server.

The problem is I can't find a way to setup traefik to allow the web traffic to be redirected on the right container depending on the entrypoint.

Here is my traefik TOML :

```
 logLevel = "ERROR"

defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[acme]
email = "myemail@mybiz.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onDemand = true
onHostRule = true
delayDontCheckDNS = 0
acmeLogging = true

[[acme.domains]]
  main = "mydomain.fr"

[docker]
domain = "mydomain.fr"
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
watch = true
```

The traefik docker-compose file

```
version: '2'

services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik
    command: --docker --logLevel=DEBUG
    networks:
      - webgateway
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /dev/null:/traefik.toml
      # Support SSL
      # - ./config/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      # - ./config/acme.json:/acme.json

networks:
  webgateway:
    driver: bridge
```

My application docker-compose for DEVELOP branch

```
version: '2'

services:

  blablabla-develop:
      image: registry.gitlab.com/aaaaaa/bbbbbbb/release:6.6.6
      environment:
          - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=develop
          - SERVER_URL=http://test.mybiz.fr
          - SERVER_PORT=8090
          - JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1g
          - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://webapp_blablabla-db-develop_1:5432/xxxxx
          - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=xxxxxx
          - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
      links:
        - blablabla-db-develop
      networks:
          - web
          - back
      restart: always
      labels:
          - "traefik.backend=webapp_blablabla-develop_1"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:develop.mydomain.fr"
          - "traefik.port=8090"

  blablabla-db-develop:
      image: postgres
      environment:
          - POSTGRES_DB=xxxxx
          - POSTGRES_USER=xxxxx
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxxx
      volumes:
          - /home/aaaaa/develop/db/app:/etc/postgresql
          - /home/aaaaa/develop/db/log:/var/log/postgresql
          - /home/aaaaa/develop/db/lib:/var/lib/postgresql
          - /home/aaaaa/develop/db/lib/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      restart: always
      networks:
          - back
      labels:
          - "traefik.enable=false"

networks:
  web:
    external:
      name: traefik_webgateway
  back:
    driver: bridge
```

The docker-compose file for QA branch :

```
version: '2'

services:

  blablabla-test:
      image: registry.gitlab.com/aaaaaa/bbbbbbb/release:6.6.6
      environment:
          - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=develop
          - SERVER_URL=http://test.mybiz.fr
          - SERVER_PORT=8090
          - JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1g
          - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://webapp_blablabla-db-test_1:5432/xxxxx
          - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=xxxxxx
          - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
      links:
        - blablabla-db-test
      networks:
          - web
          - back
      restart: always
      labels:
          - "traefik.backend=webapp_blablabla-test_1"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:test.mydomain.fr"
          - "traefik.port=8090"

  blablabla-db-test:
      image: postgres
      environment:
          - POSTGRES_DB=xxxxx
          - POSTGRES_USER=xxxxx
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=xxxxx
      volumes:
          - /home/aaaaa/test/db/app:/etc/postgresql
          - /home/aaaaa/test/db/log:/var/log/postgresql
          - /home/aaaaa/test/db/lib:/var/lib/postgresql
          - /home/aaaaa/test/db/lib/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      restart: always
      networks:
          - back
      labels:
          - "traefik.enable=false"

networks:
  web:
    external:
      name: traefik_webgateway
  back:
    driver: bridge
```

When I execute docker-compose up -d for these two files, I have a warning saying that blablabla-develop_1 and blablabla-db-develop_1 are orphans. The access via develop.mydomain.fr does not work eigthter.

Hope somebody can help me for this docker/traefik setup or at least give me a useful link, the traefik doc page has not really helped me :/

Thx

Comment: I'd say you shouldn't so many different docker-compose files for different branches. Do it in one with parameters (or with two using override -f). Thus you avoid duplication and make it more maintainable

Answer (score 0):

Add setup for blablabla-develop, blablabla-db-develop, blablabla-test, blablabla-db-test in the same docker-compose file with one network for backend and one frontend network external matching the network created into the traefik docker-compose file.